# Azure SQL Elastic Performance Scale

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, azure-scheduler, azure-elastic-scale

I have Standard S1 SQL database which is fine for most tasks. However I have an overnight task that needs much more computing power.

I am wondering if anyone has experience of using scheduling to scale up the database in terms of Service Tier and Performance Level, executing one or more specific SQL tasks, and then scaling back down to the original level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote the following Azure Automation workflow for your exact scenario [[Azure SQL Database: Vertically Scale]](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-SQL-Database-e957354f/view/Discussions). In full disclosure, there is an open issue running the script against SQL Database v12 right now.  I am actively working on it and will post on the script center page when resolved.

(2/28) Update, the issue has been mitigated and the detailed steps for the temporary workaround have been posted on the main script center page.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, that looks really useful. I understand that scaling up (or down) can take some time. I presume the script commands are async, in that they do not wait for the scaling change to complete, is that correct?

Comment: That is correct, the following command issues the action to scale:

# Set the new edition/performance level 
        Set-AzureSqlDatabase $CTX –Database $Db –ServiceObjective $ServiceObjective –Edition $Using:Edition -Force